# File input into a dynamic 2D array

Tags: c++, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a program that generates solutions for the game peg solitaire.However I am really stuck on the beginning part. Which is taking a file congaing the starting board and than placing those values in a dynamic 2D array. Currently I get the error message subscript out of range when I run my program. So the starting board begins with the top line of a txt file congaing two numbers which represent the rows and columns and than followed by the board itself contains chars. My deconstructor and tostring are commented out because they are having issues as well, and I fell they are connected.

for example (not an actual board just representation of NxN and char I wish to load into 2d array)

3 3

sss

sss

sss

header file

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char PegType;

class PegBoard
{
private:
   int numRows;
   int numCols;
   char ** pegBoard;

public:
//constructor
PegBoard(istream &input);

//deconstructor
 ~PegBoard();


//toString
 void toString() ;
}; //end of header file
```

implementation file

```
  #include "PegBoard.h"

//constructor
PegBoard::PegBoard(istream &input){
 string dummyline;
 numCols = 0;
 numRows = 0;
 pegBoard = new char* [numRows];

 //get rows and cols
 input >> numRows;
 input >> numCols;
 //generate starting board from txt file
    while(!input.eof()){
        for(int r=0; r <= numRows; r++){  
            getline(input,dummyline);
            pegBoard[r] = new char[numCols];
            for(int c=0; c<= numCols; c++){
                 pegBoard[r][c] = dummyline[c];
            }
        }
    }
}//end constructor

//deconstructor
PegBoard::~PegBoard(){
//  for (int i=0; i <= numRows; i++)
    //  delete [] peg[i];
    //  delete [] peg;
}//end deconstructor

//toString
void PegBoard::toString() {
    /*
    for(int r=0; r<numRows; r++){
        for(int c=0; c<numCols; c++)
            cout << peg[r][c];
            cout << endl;
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing bad,very bad is that you're using numRows before assigning to it value from file.
So just change to this:

```
 //get rows and cols
 input >> numRows;
 input >> numCols;
pegBoard = new char* [numRows];
```

And in your for loop you only should go from 0 to numRows (numCols) -1. Or like this:

```
for(int r=0; r < numRows; r++)
```

because when you define array size, you say numRows,so we count [0,numRows)

Comment: I feel silly, but I made that change and am still getting the same error message.